# How to generate an associated token account when generating the one in SOL?

Tags: spl-token, wallet, spl

I have a web service in which I'll be generating to my users wallets in SOL and in USDT/USDC. The wallets will be custodial, for deposits, and it has to be this way.

**And I need to obtain and parse** incoming TXs in SOL and USDT/USDC, via API.

As I've found out, in order be able to see and parse incoming TXs in USDT/USDC, **I'll have to** create and use the 2 assosiated accounts for USDT/USDC **first**. In other words, the API endpoint `getSignaturesForAddress(...)`, if called with the **main** - `SOL` - address, will only return the TXs sent in SOL, and not the ones send in USDT/USDC.

To parse the TXs for the tokens, `getSignaturesForAddress(spl_token_addrr)` requires an address of any of those.

Correct?

If so, **how will I resolve all this?**

Will I have to generate the main - SOL - account first, for each new wallet, **then** top it up to pay the rent (0.005 SOL), and **only then** generate  assosiated addresses in USDT/USDC for it?

How to generate an assosiated account in `web3.js`?

---

Otherwise, is there a better and simpler solution?

**update 1:**

if a user for the very time sends some USDT to the SOL address, thus creating a USDT address **by himself**, this will work fine. However, how will I check and get the address of, **not create it,** an assossiated account for USDT by the main SOL one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not 100% sure to get your question properly, but you can get the associated token account address with this code :

```
    import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, getAssociatedTokenAddress } from '@solana/spl-token';

export async function getAssociatedTokenAccount(mint, owner) {
  
  const tokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mint,
        owner,  
        true,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    );
  
  return tokenAccount;
}
```

please note that this code will always return an address, even if it doesn't exists.

If you need it to be created, you have to check by yourself if it exists and you can create it if needed.

If i understood properly your use case, you have to create first a wallet address, then you can create the associated token accounts. IMO, there is no need to have SOL in the wallet - not sure about this though.

If a user sends USDT/USDC first, this should create the associated token account (depends on how it is sent, because the user has to funds those accounts, so if this is sent with phantom for example, it should be done automaticaly)

Comment: my goal, ideally, is to generate USDT/USDC addresses right after I've generated the main address in SOL **and** do so without having to deposit any SOL for this. Is it possible? Later on I or a user will deposit some SOLs to it

Comment: `please note that this code will always return an address, even if it doesn't exists.` -- if called multiple times, wil an address come out different each time? Provided  it's not been properly created yet

Comment: 1) you can't create the accounts without spending sol. 2) it should return always the same address, even if not created.

Comment: 2) if the main account is empty, I could generate an address for USDT, give it to a user, he'll send USDT to it and he'll also get charged by the network automatically for creating or activating an account. Correct?

Comment: how your user will send usdt ? With a wallet (like phantom for example) ?

Comment: With any wallet a user may desire to, or even directly by code -  I can't predict, nor could I control this.

Comment: if it's with a wallet, they will fund the associated token account directly, if it's with code, they would have to create it first if it doesn't exist yet.
Do you have any question left ? (otherwise please accept my answer :))

Comment: `they would have to create it first if it doesn't exist yet.` --- what do you mean by "create"?

Comment: `if it's with a wallet, they will fund the associated token account directly,` - the Solana blockchain iisn't aware whether the action of "sending USDT" is being done by a wallet or code. Why is it that with a wallet there'll be no need to `create` a remote assossiated account first, unlike with code?

Comment: i haven't saif there is no need (it is needed of course), it's just that with the wallet app, it checks if the account exists and if it doesn't, it adds an instruction to create it, like you have to do with code.
What i mean by create is adding an instruction to the transaction in order to create the associated token account before sending tokens. Check this link, here is the function that returns the needed instruction : https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.html